# Build kernel module on locked bootloader

Tags: kernel

I have an device with locked bootloader, but i have the kernel source and prebuilt kernel. I have two questions:

1. Do i need the kernel to be built to get a module working?
2. Can i get an module to be built on the prebuilt kernel?

Comment: What's the point when you can't replace (flash) the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shortcut your two questions: you can't load a module you've compiled yourself without unlocking the bootloader.

Technically you can compile a kernel module without compiling the kernel yourself, if you have the kernel sources and you know what options were used to compile the kernel; it's just easier to compile the kernel and modules at the same time. But that doesn't matter anyway, because you need to be able to sign the kernel and/or sign a system image containing your kernel module, in order for that module to load. You need to unlock the bootloader to avoid the signature check.